# if value is empty display nothing

Tags: php, javascript, if-statement

On one file I have this code:

```
if (theForm.lqd_9.value == "")
{
    alert("You have forgotten to specify - Description!");
    theForm.lqd_9.focus();
    return (false);      
    <tr>
       <td class="theadingt" align="center" height="14" width="180">
             <b>Description:<span lang="en-us"><font color="#ff0000">*</font></span></b></td>
        <td class="theading" align="left" height="14" width="545">
    <textarea cols='48' rows='6' name="lqd_9"></textarea></td>
   </tr>
```

and on the receiving file I have this:

```
<?php echo $_POST["lqd_9"]; ?>
```

How can I make the code to not display anything if it's left empty?

Comment: `lert("You have forgotten an A");`

Comment: If it's empty, echoing it wouldn't make any difference.

Comment: thanks, it was a typo when I was writing the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use methods like [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["lqd_9"])){
 echo $_POST["lqd_9"];
} 
?>
```

## OR

```
<?php 
if(!empty($_POST["lqd_9"])){
 echo $_POST["lqd_9"];
} 
?>
```

## update

It's better to use both as below.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["lqd_9"]) && !empty($_POST["lqd_9"])){
 echo $_POST["lqd_9"];
} 
?>
```

[PHP isset() vs empty() vs is_null()](http://www.virendrachandak.com/techtalk/php-isset-vs-empty-vs-is_null/)

Comment: isset is different from empty.. the best is to use both!

Comment: that's why I have post a link at the end

Comment: just a quick question how can I also make it when there is no text entered to show: No information available

Comment: Why would you need both? Using both is equivalent to just using `!empty()` as far as I can tell.

Comment: Using both isn't needed... In this case, you only need empty() - as it checks to see if it is set as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its a best practice to use isset and to escape characters like:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["lqd_9"]) && trim($_POST["lqd_9"]) !== ""){
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["lqd_9"], ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Don't forget the other two arguments to `htmlspecialchars()` :) not all php versions are utf8 by default.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($_POST["lqd_9"]) && $_POST["lqd_9"]){
     ###ALL CODE
}
```

This simple check will guarantee that there is post data lqd_9 :)

ISSET checks if its set at first time else if you are using it without its set it may throw error. And the second check is checking if lqd_9 is different from FALSE (if its empty its false else its true)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?= isset(($_POST['lqd_9']) ? $_POST['lqd_9'] : ''; ?>
```

That said, it's a bad practice to display user provided data without saniting it. You could create a small convenience function that returns sanitized data /ex:

```
<?php
function sanitize($str) {
    return filter_var($str, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
}
?>

<?= isset($_POST['lqd_9']) ? sanitize($_POST['lqd_9']) : '' ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_POST['lqd_9']){
       echo $_POST['lqd_9'];
   }
?>
```